# How can I share a python Class between applications without installing it?

Tags: python, import

I have a flask application, that accesses a DB via Class that encapsulates DB access.  I need to use this same class outside of the flask application for some regular jobs that access the same db.

```
/databases/database.db
/website/application/myblueprint/views.py
/website/application/myblueprint/db_class.py
/scripts/log_reading.py
```

Both views.py and log_reading.py need to use db_class.py, but you can't import from above your own package.

1. I could make db_class.py it's own application and install it each
   venv, but then every time I edit I have to reinstall it in each
   place.  Plus there's the overhead of the setup stuff for a single module.
2. I could put the file in python site path, either by moving
   it or by adding to the path, but that feels wrong and I'm not sure
   would work with venvs.
3. I could sym link, that also feels wrong.

I'm not using flask models for the DB, but I don't think that would solve my problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use db or session then you have to create application context, outside of application context you can't use it.

```
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
import os

APP_SETTINGS = os.getenv("APP_SETTINGS", "your config path")

def _create_db_session(self, connection_string):
    engine = create_engine(connection_string)
    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
    session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    return session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(APP_SETTINGS)
db_url = app.config.get("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI")
session =_create_db_session(db_url)

#then you can use
# session.query to query database
# session.commit(), session.remove()
# same operations you do normally with DB session
```

Comment: That's not my question.  Within a flask app I can access my dB, with or without models.  If I want to share the class that encapsulates dB access between two python apps whilst not having to constantly install the app on venvs, how do I do that?